# Cannot spread KVP array in React/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a logic in which I am iterating an array and need to add long/lat as markers on map. For uniqueness I am pushing them in array but IDK why i am unable to spread it next time.

```
this.setState((state) => {
    var tripEndFlags = [...this.state.tripEndFlags];

    if (point.ShowTripEndFlag) {
        console.log('tripEndFlags', tripEndFlags);

        tripEndFlags[point.latitude + "-" + point.longitude] = {
            latitude: point.latitude,
            longitude: point.longitude,
        };
    }

    return {
        index: state.index + 1,
        cordinates: [...state.cordinates, {
            latitude: point.latitude,
            longitude: point.longitude,
        }],
        tripEndFlags: tripEndFlags,
    };
}, () => {
    console.log('endFlags', this.state.tripEndFlags);
    this.props.AnimateCamera(point);
});
```

Output:
It prints endFlags as empty array in beginning since there are no condition is not matched but later it sets then resets the array.

endFlags [24.943138299999998-67.0789016: {…}]

Later it starts to show endFlags [] like before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For uniqueness I am pushing them in array

Array elements are not unique `[0,0,1]` is perfectly valid (how else would you store vectors for instance?). I think you mix up arrays (`[]`, value storage ordered by index) and objects (`{}`, key-value storage)

Something like `var tripEndFlags = {...this.state.tripEndFlags}` would be more correct.